# Is there any pdf viewer with dark mode?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

Basically, I want a viewer which has a night mode or a dark mode so that I can change a pdf with a white background and black text to a dark background and light coloured text.

Comment: `qpdfview` (lubuntu 18.10 & up standard viewer) allows you to change colors of background, paper-color & presentation backgrounds to any of a huge list (30+) of selections.

Comment: Which pdf file viewers have you researched? Both okular and qpdfview can invert colors unless the pdf file is composed of images.

Comment: I used search terms "dark mode","pdf viewer", "night mode" coudn't get any result. qpdfview.Till now I was using default docuement viewer. Thanks, qpdfview have the feature that I was asking for.

Comment: qpdfview is awesome! I love the `Invert colors` option in its view menu and it has the most sensible scrolling I've seen in any pdf viewer. Thanks @guiverc I have a new goto pdf viewer!

Comment: @guivers - **`qpdfview` cannot change text color** the way you said; if the text is black it stays black in all those 30+ selections. The "invert color" option under "View", as LonnieBest said, can change that, but only  to white-on-black, which is not as comfortable as adjusted colors like light-grey on dark-grey etc (which other viewers can provide).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**This method is only for text only documents. Otherwise the image colors will be inverted.**

You can install Evince document viewer from [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads) link and open it.Then goto the options on the top right corner as seen in the picture.

[image]

Then select **Inverted colors**. This will help you to read white text on a black background.
In Evince document viewer **3.30.1+** select **Night Mode**.

Comment: Thanks I already had Evince document viewer installed but didn't know that inverted colors can do this.

Comment: @UbuntuLover You are welcome, yes it comes pre-installed.

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for bookmark in Evince?

Comment: @UbuntuLover Actually could not find it here... https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/shortcuts.html.en

Comment: In my Document Viewer (3.30.1) the option is called 'Night Mode'.

Comment: @muclux May be, I still have 3.28.4, because I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: `This method is only for text only documents. Otherwise the image colors will be inverted.` - Non-text images will look distorted in image-based pdfs, but in  those images that are text-images (scanned text saved as image-pdf) inverting colors gives the same result as in text-based pdfs: black on white is replaced with white on black.

Comment: Nothing better than finding out that the feature you're looking for you already have!

Comment: [This menu has changed in recent versions](https://superuser.com/q/1739289/865660)

Comment: @J.Mini already updated the answer below the picture.

Answer (score 20):

Simply inverting colors doesn't provide the best readability (being limited to very bright white text on very dark black background), although it can improve it a lot in a dark environment.

Evince and also [pdfstudioviewer](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/) can do that, which will result in something like this (in both image and text pdfs):

[image]

PDF readers that can change **both page and text color in both text and image (scanned text) pdf files** are:

- **Okular** (in newer versions, like 1.9.3). See below.
- [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/)  More details in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195835/925128), also
- [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) - as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/619793/925128).

I think this is more readable:

[image]

[image]

---

### UPDATE on Okular:

In newer versions of Okular (like 1.9.3) both font and page colors can be edited — and a dark-mode look can be enabled — through a new and rather non-intuitive setting, under *Configure Okular - Accessibility - Color mode: Change Dark and Light Colors*, by selecting a light color for dark and a dark one for light color option.

[image]

Then, for easy access, configure toolbar and add *Toggle change color*. It works for picture/scanned pages too.

[image]

[image]

---

**qpdf** can change both text and background color but **only in text-based pdf files** - and that in a rather odd manner: only background/"paper" color can be set directly, the font color can only be "inverted" from white to black: so, the trick is to set the direct color in such a way as to result in a desired color when inverted (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1397319/925128) answer, which provides an example of good setting for a proper dark mode result: Background color: `#41403b,` Paper color: `#cccbca`).

Just for text-based pdfs, **Adobe Reader 9** can separately set both font and page colors (when it can still be used in Linux: more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/472596/925128)).

See my linked answer on **Foxit Reader**, which can match the two above but has no dark GUI and no full-screen.

Calibre Ebook Reader (like many ebook readers) can edit colors of font and page, but it can also open **text-based** pdfs.

---

By the way: in case somebody needs to transform a scanned text saved as image-pdf so that it becomes more readable by removing colored (gray, yellowish or pinkish) background, a good tool is ScanTailor, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1359849/925128).

Comment: Master PDF Editor is news to me. Glad to hear about that.

Answer (score 6):

Atril from MATE DE also has *Inverted Colors* mode (accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>):

> [image: Inverted Colors mode in Atril]

You can install Atril with `sudo apt-get install atril`.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to go for Okular, one of the best readers for Linux platform. It is free of cost and provides features such as

1. Night view mode
2. Annotate and Markup tools
3. Text extraction from PDF file
4. Border trimming, and lot more.

Comment: how do you enable the night view?

Comment: not sure if there is a night view, I use okular and change the colors in the accessibility settings: Settings->Configure Okular...->Accessibility->tick change color, and I use change dark&light color, I then choose as dark color a lighter gray and as light color a very dark gray. This tuns the text light gray and the background dark gray, which imo is nice. I really don't like the invert color stuff, 100%white on 100%black is just too much contrast for me and strains way more than more gentile (gray) colors.

Comment: I had just discovered that and updated my answer when I saw your comment!

Answer (score 3):

I found all these answer are usefull then finally found this

```
xcalib -i -a
```

This inverts all the screen , everywhere. So no need to find if a particular software have this feature or not.
I can set a hotkey and now whenever I want dark mode I just need to press the Hotkey, works even for browser.

Installation

```
sudo apt-get install xcalib
```

Comment: That's cool! I'll be setting up autokey shortcuts that link to various xcalib adjustments. It even allows you to adjust contrast and brightness. Thanks for sharing this; what a jewel.

Answer (score 2):

how about Foxit Reader? ( a big name on Windows - although the Linux version seems like minimal version )

It allows us to view a PDF in many better ways than Inverted Colors so you can choose what is suit for you ( and your eyes)

[image: ![enter image description here]

thanks @bodqhrohro for the image

For Night:

Black:
[image]

Darkmode:
[image]

For Day:

Yellow :
[image]

Pink:
[image]

Blue:
[image]

Get it officially here: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/

Comment: For the moment the problem with FoxitReader when we are looking for dark mode is that it has [no dark gui](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/167502-dark-mode?p=172002#post172002) and [no full screen](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/161702-ubuntu-64-bit-fullscreen), which means that a large part of the screen stays very white.

Comment: I install Foxit all the time for my windows users, but had no clue it ran on Linux too.

Comment: _>(don't know why I cannot screenshot that menu )_

I strongly suggest `scrot -d 5` for such cases ;) [Here's my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCfA6.png); feel free to replace your photo with it.

Comment: thank @bodqhrohro, I updated it,

And also thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

After testing through many pdf readers, I found qpdfview is the best application for viewing pdf in dark mode.

Foxit is the best in term of dark mode colors configuration, but it can't view djvu, there's no dark theme for the UI.

Here is my qpdfview's setup for dark mode, it should work for scanned pdf/djvu, and vector pdf.

```
View > Invert Colors
View > Composition > Darken with paper color
```

<Invert colors> option ensures that scanned documents and images (which almost are in light colors) are in dark mode.
When using <Invert colors> option, the paper color and background color should be light colors, such as:

```
Settings > Graphics
Background color: #41403b
Paper color: #cccbca
```

Here is the result:

Vector pdf, with colored texts
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwHod.png)

Scanned djvu
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MiJU.png)

Comment: Just a note those links wont be there later.

Answer (score 1):

[Sioyek](https://sioyek.info) is a newcomer on the scene, but has quickly become my favorite PDF reader.

It has both a dark mode and a custom colors mode. Mine look like this:

**Dark**

[image: dark mode]

**Custom**

[image: custom colors]

**Normal**

[image: normal color]

But that's just my setup.  You can make it whatever you want.

To set custom colors, create the file `$HOME/.config/sioyek/prefs_user.config` and include a section such as:

```
custom_background_color 0.075 0.082 0.094
custom_text_color 0.529 0.686 0.875
```

Where the numbers correspond to r g b values between 0 and 1. E.g., `1 1 1` would be white and `0 0 0` would be black, `1 0 0` would be red, etc.

Comment: Could you add info on how to set the custom colors?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Compiz WM with "Color filter" plugin installed, you can enable any of several nightmode filters for any windows.

Answer (score 0):

i was searching for X software too and i could not find one  my bad solution...using vim with a plugin  ( Plug 'makerj/vim-pdf') let you do it  just make sure your terminal is readable and you book as no real image and your set
here a link to the "plugin"
https://github.com/makerj/vim-pdf

Answer (score 0):

## WPS Office 11

**WPS Office** since v11 has a PDF viewer with Dark mode that works quite well (i.e. not just simple colour inverting). It also has Sepia and Eye Protection mode.

[image]

You can install it from:

- [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.wps.Office) (I recommend this option)
- [snap](https://snapcraft.io/wps-office)