# Fix Okular snap error

Tags: 18.04, xfce, snap, okular

I have installed Okular from Snapcraft, initially it didn't work, but then it did, after removing and installing with the Snap Store app.

After a while it stopped working.

```
~$ okular
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried to fix with:

```
sudo snap refresh okular --devmode --edge
```

no luck.

Comment: Does ot work if you start it from the UI, not the CLI?

Comment: @schaiba - no. reinstalling made it work at some point. then stopped starting.

Comment: I'm wondering about `libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`. Why should Okular, being a qt app, require that?

Comment: Please `snap refresh okular --stable` (without devmode) and paste the full output of `snap version` and `snap run okular`