# Is there a PDF reader and editor with dark mode and multi-color highlights?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

The use cases are: A GOOD dark mode (if possible not only inverted colors). Highlights with different colors. Fill some tests (for example in questions where you have to put True or False, add comments or edit some parts of text). I achieve all of this with Adobe Pro but now I'm not in Win anymore, I hear suggestions.

Comment: Adobe Pro on wine? (I've never tried it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okular has all these features. It also allows you to change the background color (not just invert it).

`sudo apt install okular`

Annotations: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/okular/okular/annotations.html

Background color: https://askubuntu.com/a/472588/124466

It also allows one to fill up (non-XFA) forms.

Comment: Correct!. Just one observation, when I installed from Ubuntu Software I cannot configure the dark theme, but I uninstalled and then `sudo apt-get install okular` and now Okular has dark theme, thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu software is useless in my experience anyway

Comment: @qwr Ubuntu software installs the snap version, which has issues, and Canonical is forcefully pushing snaps despite those issues.

Comment: oh I didn't know that thanks for the advice since now everything from console.