# Change font color while in invert mode in Evince pdf reader

Tags: fonts, evince

Greeting!

I am looking for a step by step approach to change font color in evince while it is in invert mode by pressing ctrl + i in Ubuntu 14.04. I want the font color to be green #00EE00 hex. When googled I saw some people did it but nowhere on how to. Thus I came down to post a thread. One clue I found is that must something to do with c file called "ev-document-misc.c". I need to know the exact path for it and which line to edit to cause the font color change. I look forward to hearing from you geeks!

https://git.gnome.org/browse/evince/...ocument-misc.c

To ​devav2​

I read your comment on "How to change pdf background color in evince?" at askubuntu.com.  I am desperate to know how you did.  I am learning programming language of Java and tentatively saying I could understand bit of C language.  Would you be able to answer to my question below?  I have not been answered for four days.  I will really appreciate your help and elaboration in advance.  Your solution will give me a great deal of improvement in reading with my Ubuntu.

Change font color while in invert in Evince pdf reader asked by me
[How to change pdf background color in evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191579/how-to-change-pdf-background-color-in-evince)

Answer (score 0):

`ev-document-misc.c` is a source file in text format, so you cannot run it directly. It is one of the files from which the executable file `/usr/bin/evince` is [compiled](http://webopedia.com/TERM/C/compile.html).

But you [can add the source code](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) to your computer and create an altered evince from these by [following these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo).

Edit your file before you will run the `make` command.